# What's the best way to find KNN by hand?

Tags: algorithm, knn

Lets say I'm given the following and need to find 'use' KNN to predict the class label of record 15 and know beforehand that k is set to 3. What are the proper steps, regardless of table, or label or k is set to in order to do this?

The first 10 are training data, and the other 10 are testing data.

[image: Random table being used to explain KNN]

Comment: what is your distance measure? you can't embed this data in  a euclidean space. i think you are looking for decision trees.

Comment: In any case the question is better suited to http://stats.stackexchange.com as it's more about classification algorithms than their software implementation

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert the categorical data to numeric data.
For example: In case of the Astigmatism column you may use 1 for 'Yes' and 0 for 'No'.
Similarly do this for Age, Spectacle Prescription and Tear Production Rate.
Now that you have converted your categorical data to numeric values,you are ready to apply KNN.
Considering the testing data, select each row one by one and calculate its distance (can be L1 distance or L2 distance) from each point in the training set. So for the 11th data point you calculate its distance from all training points from 0 to 10. 
Note calculation of distance has become possible only because of the conversion of categorial data to numerical values.
Then after you have 10 distance values corresponding to the distance of the 11th data point with all other training datapoints, you select the 3 (As k=3) points with minimum distance,and see their labels then you select the label with the majority.
Repeat this for all testing points.